# Laravel Blade: Accessing variables in an included file returned undefined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, voyager

Laravel 5.8 
Voyager 1.2 
I'm trying to access a variable in an included file from the parent blade view.

```
<!-- parent.blade.php -->
@include('vendor.voyager.test.child')
{{$i}} 

<!-- child.blade.php -->
@for($i=1; $i<5; $i++)
   {{$i}} 
@endfor
```

I'm expecting `$i` would be `4` in the `parent.blade`. Instead I got `Undefined variable: i`. Any help?

Comment: Where does `$i`  come from? You need to assign it to the view. Your code shows you trying to display `{{$i}}` but the for-loop resets the $i variable to `1`.

Comment: `$i` was newly created inside the included file (`child.blade.php`) while iterating array I pass to to the included file

Comment: i dont think variables can go up in scope. What you define in `@include` does not become available in your parent template. It works the other way around though.

Comment: note that blades `@include` is not related to php's `include`.